# Overiding XML binding for XMLGregorianCalendar class in java webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am writing a web service client for a 3rdparty web service. The web service is using XMLGregorianCalendar to send the time stamp. When i invoked the web method I am getting an exception with error message

```
Input request field Start Date/Time has an invalid value.
Invalid DateTime value 2012-01-01T05:05:05, expected in format YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS
```

Is it possible to override the xml binding in client side of web service and if possible how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue and was able to solve it by customising the jaxb binding at client side.

You can do this by creating a jaxb customization xml and use it while generating the client stubs.

jaxb customization file that I have created is added below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema" 
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        wsdlLocation="relative url to wsdl location">

<jaxb:globalBindings>
     <jaxb:serializable/>
     <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

In the above file dateTime will be created as String in the stub. Hope that helps.

Comment: Find the explanation with screenshots on how to do it from netbeans. http://a4academics.com/blog/362-overriding-jaxb-xml-binding